# Matlab fzero function

Tags: matlab

If someone could help me answer the following question in matlab it would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to the software and am pretty confused.

Use **fzero** to approximate a root of sin(x) = cos(2x) near x = 1.

Answer (score 2):

The fzero function expects to get a function handle and a starting point. It's result is the closest point which is a root for the function. In your case, we are looking for the root of cos(2x)-sin(x)=0 near x=1. The code you need is:

```
fun = @(x)(cos(2*x)-sin(x)); % Create an anonymous function handle.
x0 = 1;                      % Set a starting point.
res = fzero(fun, x0);        % Calculate the nearest root.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question equals to finding the zeropoint of a function:

```
f=cos(2.*x)-sin(x)
```

First, create new function file for `f`:

```
function y = funczero01(x)
%Finding the zeros of the function below
y=cos(2.*x)-sin(x);

endfunction
```

Save the file with `funczero01.m` and load it to the path.
Then invoke `funczero01` in the debugger window:

```
x0=fzero('funczero01',1)
x0 =  0.52360
```

Make sure that you truly understand `fzero('func',x0)`. For more details,check **Matlab Document**.